# Send few api calls in parallel and rest serially in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance, api-testing

I have to create performance test cases based on views in UI, for example one view makes 2 api calls in parallel and third one is called after first 2 have finished. I am going to have multiple views.
How can i achieve this in Jmeter?
I created many thread groups with api calls but each of them runs serially.

Comment: you need blaze plugin for jmeter.

Answer (score 1):

Just add more virtual users to the Thread Group - this way requests will be executed by different users and you will be able to achieve the concurrency.

[image: JMeter Virtual Users Number]

If you need 2 (or more) users to execute a certain sampler at exactly the same moment - add [Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer) as a child of this sampler and set `Number of Simulated Users to Group by` to the desired amount of simultaneous users.